# What is wrong here in this angularjs code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is the code with ng-model and updating it from controller

Below is my dom element.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">   
      <input type="text" ng-model="guages" value="{{guages}}"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller, what is wrong in this.

```
function AppCtrl($scope){
console.log($scope.guages);
$scope.gauges=5; 
}
```

Comment: If think you need to give a name to your `ng-app="app-name"` where "app-name" is the name you gave to your module (i.e. `angular.module('app-name')`).

Comment: guages !== gauges

Comment: In addition to the misspelling of the variable...why are you using `value={{guages}}` isn't the value already bound to the input when using `ng-model` ?

Comment: Yeah, remove `value={{...}}`. You don't need it

Comment: So, basically, you made all the mistakes you could possibly fit in a dozen lines of code :-)

Comment: my mistake..lods of meetings and I am missing the words  that I type :)

Answer (score 4):

You have guages v.s gauges in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.gauges=5;
```

should be

```
$scope.guages=5
```